# How can I filter results by parent values, after grouping?

Tags: filter, ag-grid

Although I think this should be straightforward, I cannot seem to find the answer to this in relevant [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-filtering/).

When I group an ag-grid, the parent nodes show the grouped values. For example, I might see a sum. This part is good.

**But when I filter on this grouped grid, the filter only considers values at the leaf node level. I want to be able to filter on the aggregate parent values. How do I do this?**

To be more specific, ag-grid provides a filtering example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-filtering/

The filter values are: 0, 1, 2, 3 (the leaf node medal counts). But I want to filter by countries with sum(Gold) > 10, so I want to filter on the sums (34, 11, 35...). I am surprised the sum values don't factor anywhere into the filter dropdown and was hoping to get some direction on this.

[image]

Comment: Since you are using Set Filter which is an enterprise feature, you can raise this in the AG Grid Zendesk and get support on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received some details from ag-Grid, and thought I'd share them here to help someone else looking for same. Basically, this functionality does not yet exist.

It's a known limitation, and already part of the tracking pipeline under ticket AG-1228 (but unfortunately does not look to be slated for implementation soon):
[image]

Screenshot was taken from: https://www.ag-grid.com/pipeline/